# Replace for loop with numpy operations for diagonal band

Tags: numpy

Is it possible to generate the following array without explicit loop?

```
nrows, ncols = 5, 3 
d = np.zeros((nrows, nrows * ncols), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(nrows):
    d[i][i * ncols:(i + 1) * ncols] = 1
print(d)
```

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.eye` + `np.repeat`:

```
np.repeat(np.eye(nrows), ncols, axis=1)
```

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.einsum`:

```
nrows, ncols = 5, 3
out = np.zeros((nrows, nrows*ncols), 'u1')
np.einsum('iik->ik', out.reshape(nrows, nrows, ncols))[...] = 1
out
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import numpy as np
ix = np.indices((5,15))
d = (ix[1] //3  == ix[0]).astype(int)
d
>> array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```